# google app engine gives error "UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: MongoError: Authentication failed. emitOne (events.js)" while connecting with mlab

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-app-engine, mlab

i create a node js application and deploy it on google app engine. And i want that application connect MongoLab online database. I'm already done with creating user and setting up password in my database.

here is my node js[javascript] code of connection database using mongoose.

```
mongoose.connect("mongodb://username:password@ds243212.mlab.com:43212/userinfo",
{useNewUrlParser : true},{useMongoClient: true} ,function(err , db){
        if(err) console.log(err);
        db.collection("users").findOne({ email: {"$regex": "^" + req.body.email + "\\b", "$options": "i"
        }},function(er , mail){
          if(mail)
          {
            console.log(mail);
            res.redirect('/');
            console.log('email already taken');
          }
          else
          {

          db.collection("users").insertOne(putUser, function(error, result) {
              if(error) console.log(error);
              //console.log(result);
              console.log("1 document inserted");
            });
            res.redirect('/');
            }// 
            });
          });
```

everything is correct here still i don't know why google app engine give error that authentication failed.
please help someone.